# SQL to Mongodb using Rails + Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, nosql

I have the following document structure in Mongoid:

```
class Post
    include Mongoid::Document
    field "title", type: String
    field "body", type: String
    field "category_name", type: String
    field "category_id", type: Integer
end
```

I need to select all existing categories of posts to search. If this were SQL, I would:

```
SELECT distinct category_name, category_id FROM posts
```

How would I do this in SQL query in Mongoid?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the model to return only the category_name and category_id fields, use "only". `Post.all.only(:category_name, :category_id)` would return all posts of the db but only the values of those 2 attributes, all the other attributes would be nil.

But on Mongoid 3.1 you can do `Post.distinct(:category_name)` and it would return a list of the different category names of the posts as an array. On older versions of mongoid you can do `Post.all.distinct(:category_name)` to obtain the same return.